# How to handle 1-2 TB images in Sitecore media library

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

I have some tricky situation where I have 1-2 TB images and files. Each image can be 5-20 MB in size. I have to use them on Sitecore website. What is the best approach for uploading and handling such a huge amount of assets in Sitecore 8.2 or 9 website?

Comment: I would consider using a CDN and referencing them from your content or code. We did this for a major retailer that used Adobe cloud for all the product images.

Answer (score 4):

Individually, your sizes are not of major concern, however, once you add them all up and it gets into 1-2 TB of size, I would definitely look into alternatives.

There are several options, but they all depend on your Sitecore version, cloud/service preferences, long term needs, budget, etc. Here are just a few:

[DAM - Digital Asset Management for Sitecore](http://damforsitecore.com)

[Azure CDN Connector marketplace module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Azure_CDN_Connector.aspx)

[Sitecore CDN Connector](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_CDN_Connector.aspx)

These are just to name a few, as I am sure there are many other services and modules that could help.